# Apache Mod Rewrite with flexible parameters

Tags: apache

i've a problem with apache mod rewrite, I need to generate a SEF query with flexible parameters

example:

`www.myname.com/category.php?p1=itemname&p2=categoryname&p3=color&p4=size`

or

`www.myname.com/category.php?p1=itemname&p3=color`

or

`www.myname.com/category.php?p3=color&p4=size`

the combinations are always different.

how I can do it dynamically?

I started with:

`RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ category.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4`

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to build a regexp that matches in the flexible way you want.
I see some alternatives:

1. You could assing a position to earch parameter in the url, something like: 
   http://www.myname.com/param1-param2-param3-param4
   BUT in the absence of one of the parameters, the separator char should still apear in the url:
   http://www.myname.com/--color-size
   this, in my opinion the url is UGLY
2. You can evaluate the use of **URL path params**, take a look at [what every developer should know about url encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)
   with this alternative the url could be something like:
   http://www.myname.com/item;name=xxx;category=yyy;color=zzz

I do not know how search engines would consider this urls, but I imagine that it's SEF.